# Dealing with XML DOM from Javascript inside CDATA of Solr dataimport config

Tags: javascript, xml, solr, dataimporthandler

I have the following `data-config.xml` file for using dataimport from a database to Solr:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataConfig>

<dataSource name="a" driver="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/feqh/Wak1/Wak1/main.mdb"/>

<dataSource name="a1" driver="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/feqh/Wak1/Wak1/29435.mdb"/>
<dataSource name="a2" driver="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/feqh/A/2.mdb;memory=false"/>


<script><![CDATA[
    i = 0;
    bookId = 29435;


    function rownum(row, context) { 
      i++;
     // locID = row.get('LocID');
    ....................
```

I want to add a custom element to this config file under `<dataconfig>` tag as like following:

`<dbFile name="24505" id="dbFileName" />`

However, when I trying to access in the Javascript section inside CDATA by using `document.getElementById("dbFileName");` Solr returns an error recorded in the log about that `document` is not defined!

Is there any way to access this DOM element from the `<script>` of the config file?